# Ruby on rails tutorial: where is the user create view created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to follow along the ruby on rails 3 tutorial, I've completed the sign up process (through chapter 8) but nowhere has a user view: create.html.erb been created.  Since 'create' is a section in the user controller, there needs to be a corresponding 'create.html.erb' file in views/users so I get a 'missing template' error when I try to use the tutorial form to create a new user.

Where does the tutorial create the create.html.erb file?  I have paged through the tutorial a couple of times and can find no trace of it.

Thanks in advance for any help.  --Fred

---

I am editing the question because for some reason the site will not let me add a comment below the responses to my question.

In UsersController... I have copied the following code directly out of the tutotrial:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    #do something here
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render = 'new'
  end
end
```

I get: missing template users/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en].....

So if It is not a missing template issue, what is it?

Comment: I am adding this comment to my post because I cannot make the "Add Comment" box+button below the responses work!

Answer (score 1):

create is an intermediary action, it does not require a view. in your create function make sure you do a redirect_to or a render view to something. here you can also populate a flash with messages corresponding to the success of the function (validation errors, succes for save etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new record, you actually call the **new** method, which does have an associated view called **new.html.erb**. The **create** method is called when you hit the "submit" button in the **new.html.erb** view, and there is no view for **create** - it is just a method that runs without a view.

Same applies for the **update** method which doesn't have it's own view, but which is "friends" with the edit action, whose associated view is called edit.html.erb.

Delete method is different

Comment: sorry, the zzz line above was to test the 'add comment' feature which I couldn't get to work. so naturally it works with a meaningless comment!